# CSS-styled paragraphs with paragraph numbering and sidenotes

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to put a text on the web with paragraph numbers and sidenotes. I'm using Huckleberry Finn as a test: see http://jsfiddle.net/29Mdt/.

I'd like to have the paragraph numbers in the margin on the left, and the sidenotes in the margin on the right. This is extremely easily done with tables in HTML, but I'm trying to do it with CSS, and I'm a beginner to CSS. An earlier question about paragraph numbers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314884/div-with-paragraphs-with-paragraph-numbers-aligned-and-outside-the-div-see-sketc), but I did not find the responses at all helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you do it with <ul> and <li>?

Comment: I'm skeptical about that, I guess because the text contains problem areas where it's a real judgment call as to where to put the next paragraph number. Thus I'd like to make sure the numbers are subject to manual control. Also, is there a way to pull list numbers back into the left margin and remove their period?

Comment: @Gerben: I've tried to, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 9):

One approach:

```
.chapter {
    counter-reset: paragraph;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.page p {
    width: 400px;
}
.page p:before {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    color: #CCC;
    content: counter(paragraph);
    counter-increment: paragraph;
}
.sidenote {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 420px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #E22;
    width: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="chapter">
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Tom Sawyer</h1>

        <p>You don't know about me...</p>

        <!-- sidenote to the paragraph following the aside tag -->
        <aside class="sidenote">The widow she cried over me...</aside>
        <p>Now the way that the...</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: By the way, this is using CSS2.1 counter: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters

Comment: @Dave2 The 'text-indent' is interfering. Try using absolute positioning on the 'p:before', e.g.: 'left: 5px;' instead of 'margin-left: -20px;'

Comment: @asdf I see. Thanks. Is there any way to fix the first paragraph (which isn't indented)?

Comment: @Dave2 'p:before' now uses absolute positioning 'left', hence it will be placed consistently on the left-axis (x) throughout the page. Try adding 'text-indent: 0' to 'p:before'.

Comment: @asdf OK, now I'm thinking the only thing that causes problems is "p:first-letter". If I can get that fixed, I'll be in good shape!: http://jsfiddle.net/29Mdt/2/

Comment: I can't believe this has no upvotes. This is biblical and legal sentence numbering using CSS.

Comment: I made http://jsfiddle.net/gp4qavef/ as a variant of 29Mdt/2 with double chapter/para numbering. BTW The <aside in that one needs to be outside the <p tags to work (or be display: differently).