# CSS-styled paragraphs with paragraph numbering and sidenotes

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to put a text on the web with paragraph numbers and sidenotes. I'm using Huckleberry Finn as a test, I asked for help [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244591/css-styled-paragraphs-with-paragraph-numbering-and-sidenotes), and I've been making progress.

But now I'm running into another problem. I can get the sidenotes to work, but only by dropping out of the main paragraph styling (see *link removed because of link limits for newbies*). Not only does this seem like bad programming, but it screws up the "p + p" indentation scheme. But if I *don't* drop out, then the sidenotes get their own paragraph numbers and everything is completely ruined (see *link removed because of link limits for newbies*).

Does anyone know what to do? Thanks.

EDIT #1: I've tried to make use of the p.text idea recommended by bbg below, but the indentation scheme is still messed up. I've tried `p.text:before` and `p.text + p.text` and similar variations, but nothing seems to work. I'm losing my mind.

EDIT #2: In an effort to attract help, I've adjusted the widths to make things easier to take in visually in the jsFiddle screens. (1) Dropped-out sidenotes → indentation failure: http://jsfiddle.net/Keh65/5/. (2) Not-dropped-out sidenotes → numbering/everything failure: http://jsfiddle.net/Keh65/6/.

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to use p tags for the sidenotes?

Comment: can you shown any diagram to know what you want to achive ?

Comment: @natedavisolds: I use p tags just for styling purposes. Is there something else I could do to style the sidenotes?

Comment: @sandeep: A diagram might be too difficult. But here's a simple explanation: apart from paragraph 1, I want every paragraph to be indented (2, 3, 4). But currently, only 3 is indented, and the indentation of 2 and 4 is being canceled by the sidenotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave2;  as per i understand your question may be [that's](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Keh65/4/) you want . If i am not right please tell me.
i am give `p ~ p` instead of `p + p` & i am removing `p` from `.sidenot` & given `span` instead of it .

Comment: I just now saw your comment. Let me look!

Comment: I think you may have solved the problem! I'm still messing with it, but it seems to work so far. Thank you so much. I'll start reading about `p ~ p` to see how it avoids this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add another class name (I used `class="text"`) for the main body paragraphs, to distinguish them from the note paragraphs.

```
<p class="text">
```

Then use that new class name to define the increment:

```
p.text {
   counter-increment: paragraph;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Keh65/3/

Note that 'paragraph' is an arbitrary name for the counter of your choosing, and is not necessarily tied to the html `<p>` element.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this solves the original problem: I still need to drop out of the main paragraph styling, which ruins the "p + p" indentation scheme.

Comment: Oh I see.  No, I guess it doesn't help!